# Access Google Drive using Arduino

Tags: logging, arduino, google-drive-api

I am using an Arduino board for data logging. My Arduino is connected to the Internet through a WiFi shield.  The Arduino uses a kind of C++ programming language.

Does anybody know how I can access a file from Google Drive using the Arduino?

Comment: You might want to also ask this question on http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your Arduino for data logging you probably want to log the data your sensors receive and upload it to your google drive account.

Well accesing google drive is no trivial task you need to interface with OAuth protocol so as an alternative you might want to upload to a google docs spreadsheet.

A simple tutorial can be found [here](http://myinternetofthings.wordpress.com/2011/06/11/arduino-to-google-docs/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your arduino can do HTTP post, you can do this:
http://leftbraintinkering.blogspot.com/2011/07/datalogging-with-google-spreadsheets.html

I'm still working on figuring out the specifics for my own application though so for now all I can offer is the link, but it should get ya movin.

Answer (score 0):

Using the new google spreadsheets, you can access the API and write directly to the sheet from a service like Temboo.

https://temboo.com/arduino/others/update-google-spreadsheet